# "Apps that simulate multi-App widget experiences will be rejected."-Apple Guideline. Examples or specifications?

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone specify or give examples of cases that would be rejected based off this guideline? For example, would Apple reject an app that blocks other apps from being used at a given point? Any elucidations to this guideline would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of Alternate desktop/home screen environment is something like this in the link - [Apple rejects Taposé because it's too advanced(?) - Pocketables](http://www.pocketables.com/2012/01/apple-rejects-tapose-because-its-too-advanced.html)

From the video in the above link you can notice that we can switch between different applications from within the app which is acting as an alternative home screen environment (as apple says).

An example of multi-app widget experience: In the screenshot below you can notice multiple widgets (weather, Date & Time, Music, Facebook) in the app.
[iDashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmgyg.jpg)